# Check Successive Records from a Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to pull out a report for my marketing team about the field work done by our sales guys, each sales guy will have check_in time and check_out time to know how much he spends on a shop. Similarly, I need to compare the checkout_time and check_time and get the time difference between those two records.

Here is my sample table:

```
S.No   User_ID    Name      Check_in_Time          Check_out_Time

1       123       XYZ        2019-04-11 09:00:00    2019-04-11 09:15:00
2       123       XYZ        2019-04-11 09:20:00    2019-04-11 09:30:00
3       123       XYZ        2019-04-11 10:00:00    2019-04-11 10:15:00
4       123       XYZ        2019-04-11 11:00:00    2019-04-11 11:30:00
5       567       ZZZ        2019-04-11 10:00:00    2019-04-11 10:30:00
6       567       ZZZ        2019-04-11 11:00:00    2019-04-11 11:30:00
```

Now I need to compare the 1st Check_out_Time with 2nd Check_in_Time with the time difference, like wise I need to compare all the check_out and check_in time differences for every user for a given date.

Please help in writing a MySQL Query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution for MySQL earlier 8.0 (without `ROW_NUMBER` support):

```
SELECT 
    t1.User_Id, 
    t1.Name, 
    t1.check_out_time, 
    t2.Name, 
    t2.Check_in_time, 
    TIMEDIFF(t2.Check_in_time, t1.check_out_time) AS diff 
FROM (
    SELECT *, IF(@prev <> User_ID, @rn:=0, @rn), @prev:=User_ID, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM table_name JOIN (SELECT @prev:='') init_prev JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) init_rn
    ORDER BY User_ID, Check_in_Time, Check_out_Time
)t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, IF(@prev <> User_ID, @rn:=0, @rn), @prev:=User_ID, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM table_name JOIN (SELECT @prev:='') init_prev JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) init_rn
    ORDER BY User_ID, Check_in_Time, Check_out_Time
)t2 ON t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID AND t1.rn + 1 = t2.rn
WHERE DATE(t2.Check_in_time) = '2019-04-11' AND DATE(t1.check_out_time) = '2019-04-11'
```

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use the following solution using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT 
    t1.User_Id, 
    t1.Name, 
    t1.check_out_time, 
    t2.Name, 
    t2.Check_in_time, 
    TIMEDIFF(t2.Check_in_time, t1.check_out_time) AS diff 
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY User_ID, Check_in_Time, Check_out_Time) rn 
    FROM table_name
)t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY User_ID, Check_in_Time, Check_out_Time) rn 
    FROM table_name
)t2 ON t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID AND t1.rn + 1 = t2.rn
WHERE DATE(t2.Check_in_time) = '2019-04-11' AND DATE(t1.check_out_time) = '2019-04-11'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a967857c9655016ee2a734ab372ec46)

Comment: Thanks for the above query, This work pretty well with MySQL 8.0, but my MySQL version is 5.7

Comment: Hey thanks for the above update, it worked pretty well

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using mysql version 8.0 then following would be the solutions,

```
SELECT 
t1.User_Id, 
t1.Name, 
t1.check_out_time, 
t2.Name, 
t2.Check_in_time, 
TIMEDIFF(t2.Check_in_time, t1.check_out_time) AS diff 
FROM (
   SELECT *, @row := @row+1 as rank
   FROM table_name, (select @row :=0)
   ORDER BY User_ID,Check_in_time
)t1 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT *, , @row1 := @row1+1 as rank
     FROM table_name, (select @row1 :=0)
     ORDER BY User_ID,Check_in_time
)t2 ON t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID AND t1.rank + 1 = t2.rank
WHERE DATE(t2.Check_in_time) = '2019-04-11' AND DATE(t1.check_out_time) = '2019-04-11'
```